# C program to split char using strtok and strchr

Tags: c

I have a following to C program to split char*

its a user entred value in the format usually "111/222". (code produce correct output)

In some cases , the value entered  is "/222".

```
   char* ptr ="/222" ; 
   char* val1 , *val2;

   val1 = strchr( ptr, '/');
   if ( val1 != NULL)
     val1++;

   val2 = strtok(ptr,"/");
```

myoutput :

val1 = 222

val2 = 222

i dont know how to get

val1 = ""  (as empty char)

val2 = 222

Thanks in advance for ur help!

Comment: The code shown is expected to crash.

Comment: using printf i have the output as val1= 222 and val 2 = 222

Comment: In C string literals like your `"/222"` are not modifiable, but `strtok` modifies its argument. So your code snippet has undefined behavior.

Comment: What output shall be generated when inputting `"123/456"`?

Comment: Could you clear up your question a bit? I have no idea what you're really asking. In your code val1 will always point to the argument after the slash, or be null if there is no slash. You seem to expect the results to be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to check if your string start with / or not. If then, set val1 to "" and val2 have to point to (ptr + 1). else do what you do currently